# Does Elastic Beanstalk misassign security groups in environment creation?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

When I create an environment with a VPC in Elastic Beanstalk, the VPC configuration page requires selection of a VPC Security Group. After creation of the environment, two security groups are automatically created; a VPC Security Group and a Load Balancer Security Group.

On the Configuration -> Instances page, there are two security groups listed in the EC2 security groups field. The first is the security group selected during setup, the second is the automatically created VPC Security Group. In our case, the security group selected during setup is extraneous.

I have two questions. Why does EB require selection of a security group? And should the Load Balancer Security Group be included in the EC2 security groups field on the Instances page?